# Entity Framework dont recognize sql geographic type

Tags: entity-framework

I have created an edmx item using database first, in one of my tables is have a column whuc is geographic type, when I am looking on the generated entities this property is missing
is there a way to add it?

Comment: What version of EF and the .NET framework do you use?

Comment: My mistake - it is regular ADO.Net entity data model on VS2010 Framework 4.0

Comment: Spatial types are available in EF 5 and higher.

Comment: available also in net4.0 or only 4.5?

Comment: @li-raz, Only in .NET 4.5 with EF 5. But with EF 6.0, it is also available with .NET 4.0